# Generating report from two separate tables using visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I've got a table(concepttable) which has stored emotions in conceptname column such as happy sad etc. Users can add more emotions in it via asp web form. 
In the same dataset there is another table called (blog) that has a string of multiple blog entries with there entry dates.

How would i go around by using a **service report** to use a droplist that displays the stored emotions in (conceptname) and then shows how many times that selected emotion such as sad has appeared in all blogcontent strings in the blog table?

Any help is appreciated, I've been trying blindly using joins and full text searches but am not certain what way to go around to achieve this.
Ive attached an image showing the data sources.[image]

The output i want to achieve is a chart similar to this:

[image]

Sorry if this is vague, add a comment if your not sure what i mean. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What field in the blog table holds the concept?

Comment: the concept is held in a separate table under conceptname, the blogtable only contains the entries. So the two tables need to be compared against each other? or joined?

Comment: Ok, so your blog table has a text field called CONTENT?   And within that field, emotions such as Sad, Angry, etc can be entered?  Is that right?

Comment: no sorry, there is a separate table to blog called CONCEPT which contains the emotions under Conceptname. CONTENT holds the blog entries in the blogtable. If you look at the 1st screenshot it shows the 2 tables there on the left. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SQL you need:

```
select conceptName,COUNT(distinct blogId) as Tot
from conceptTable ct
join blogs on content like '%'+ct.conceptName+'%'
group by conceptName
```

To get the first date a concept appears

```
select conceptName,min(inputDate) as FirstTime,COUNT(distinct blogId) as Tot
from conceptTable ct
join blogs on content like '%'+ct.conceptName+'%'
group by conceptName
```

To get the most recent date a concept appears

```
select conceptName,max(inputDate) as MostRecent,COUNT(distinct blogId) as Tot
from conceptTable ct
join blogs on content like '%'+ct.conceptName+'%'
group by conceptName
```

To get all dates

```
select conceptName,inputDate,COUNT(distinct blogId) as Tot
from conceptTable ct
join blogs on content like '%'+ct.conceptName+'%'
group by conceptName,inputDate
```

Comment: While this do what you are asking, it might not work as expected.  What happens if the user enters   I am not happy in their blog?  The code will count that as an occurrence of "happy", even though the user who entered the entry is not happy....  There are a lot of gotchas like that to consider.

Comment: Hi sparkey thats nearly it, but how would i get the input date from from the blog table to display as well?